# How to test code that uses DSE Cassandra/Solr?

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, functional-testing, cassandraunit

I am working on an application where we are interfacing with Datastax Enterprise edition (we are auto syncing with solr).

I was wondering how can this application be efficiently tested.

I was considering embedded cassandra for testing but the caveat there is that we are using `solr_query` to query Cassandra.

The alternative is to setup a test keyspace in the real node and run the tests using that keyspace.

But I would like to write functional test cases that has no dependency on the real cassandra database.

I would like to know about the best practices that people follow to handle such scenarios.

Cheers,

Utsav

Answer (score 0):

The DataStax java driver does this type of thing using `CCM`. `CCM` is a tool to stand up / simulate a small cluster (both DSE and OSS C* are supported) on a single machine.

Check out their code here https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/3.x/testing